# Merge conflict but <<<<<<< is missing from grep - how to find another user's file absence/presence based conflicts

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Another user in my group was trying to merge his local branch with one of our branches in the origin (call the origin branch **beta**). He used Gitlab and was informed there was a merge conflict. I told him I would help find the conflict.

I pulled his conflicting branch and searched for `<<<<<<<`

```
grep -lr "<<<<<<<" *
```

but only found one instance in a Guzzle file (not what we wanted).

He got back to me later and told me that a file that I had removed (from the **beta** branch he originally pulled from, *after* he had pulled) was still present on his local branch, causing the conflict.

How could I have found this file-based merge conflict? It seems to me that a `git diff` based approach is not usable here.

Comment: if we're talking about files that are currently being tracked by git and at the same point in history (same commit), a `git status` would have shown if the files were missing or not

Comment: I think he made several commits and pushes to origin for his specific branch before he tried to merge with beta

Comment: if he made several commits and pushes after you pull his repo, you would need to update your local repo before any chances were known to your repository.

A `git fetch` would have let you see his changes and a `git pull` would have merged those changes into your local repo.

Comment: no, before I pulled his repo he made those commits and pushes